# I do not understand these LESS function code (if, boolean)

Tags: css, less

I did not understand these codes LESS! thank you for helping me

```
@bg: black;
@bg-light: boolean(luma(@bg) > 50%);

div {
    background: @bg; 
    color: if(@bg-light, black, white);
}
```

and this code :

```
@some: foo;

div {
    margin: if((2 > 1), 0, 3px);
    color:  if((iscolor(@some)), darken(@some, 10%), black);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some pretty standard LESS, using `@` to declare variables, functions like `boolean()` and `luma()` to convert values into different types and formats, and logic stuff like `if()` and `x > y` to compare values and make decisions.

For a more helpful answer, you'd probably need to explain what you don't understand. Have you worked with LESS before? Is a specific function confusing, or the whole thing?

Either way, I definitely recommend reading through the LESS documentation at http://lesscss.org/, the docs there are pretty solid. Specifically relating to this case, I recommend these:

- http://lesscss.org/functions - All about functions like [`if()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#logical-functions-if) and [`iscolor()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#type-functions-iscolor); just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in your browser to search the page for the name of the function you're wondering about
- http://lesscss.org/features - The In-Depth Guide covers all the main points of LESS, including, for example, [how variables work](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature). As always, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is your friend on long pages like this!

Good luck!